# SEC (Simple Event Correlator): Handle multiple log files

Tags: logging

I've been strungling for a few days finding a good log file processor for UNIX systems.

Here is my case:

- We have an IDM system that produces lots of logs (20+)
- I need to find errors in these logs and handle them (preferably,
  I send them through nagios)
- Each logfile may contain identical errors (the same error may occur
  in multiple logfiles at the same time)
- I do not want to be spammed with emails or notifications, and these logs produce a notification each 30 seconds

I tried to tackle this with logpp, but logpp doesn't give me the option of a time window and of suppressing the same messages.
So I went over to SEC, where you have lots of powerful options.

Sadly, however, SEC seems to open all files at once and does not distinguish between logfiles. That means, if I suppress some regex condition for ten minutes, within the ten minute window, no other logfile can produce the same message. So SEC doesn't care where the error comes from, basically. I do :)

I seem to be left with two options:

1. Every time I find something, write it to a general logfile with the logname in front and write a new condition with the regex adjusted (meaning: ^Logname.*error$). But this is... too much work for 20 logs
2. OR: I use a script that sends the found entries to a log with a timestamp and calculate the window myself, which defeats the SEC purpose :)

Now my question is: has anyone got the same issues an how did you resolve them, with SEC or other logfile watchers? I cannot seem to find a good program that fits all of my needs.
Or am I wrong? Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

SEC supports matching events coming from particular sources via file contexts. File context is a logical identifier for one or several files which can be used in SEC rules for restricting the scope of matching. File contexts can be set up with the --intcontexts command line option.

If you would like to retrieve the input log file name after a regular expression match, there is a special match variable $+{_inputsrc} which is automatically set by SEC, and can be used alongside with $1, $2 and other regular match variables.

Also, you are welcome to post your question to the SEC mailing list where most of the user discussion is taking place. The list is also most likely to provide you with a quick answer.

kind regards,
risto

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Risto! I'm glad there's a way out, because SEC seems to be the right tool for me.
I will post this on the mailing list, because I need some examples to wrap my mind around it! Thanks.